# Calculating the Hessian Vector Product of a Flax NN output wrt to the inputs

Tags: jax, hessian, automatic-differentiation, flax

I am trying to get the second derivative of the output w.r.t the input of a neural network built using Flax. The network is structured as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import flax.linen as nn
import optax
from flax import optim

class MLP(nn.Module):
  features: Sequence[int]

  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x):
    for feat in self.features[:-1]:
      x = nn.tanh(nn.Dense(feat)(x))
    x = nn.Dense(self.features[-1])(x)
    return x

model = MLP([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 1])
batch = jnp.ones((32, 3)) #Dummy input to Initialize the NN
params = model.init(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), batch)
X =  jnp.ones((32, 3))
output = model.apply(params, X)
```

I can get the single derivative by using vmap over grad :

```
@jit
def u_function(params, X):
  u = model.apply(params, X)
  return jnp.squeeze(u)

grad_fn = vmap(grad(u_function, argnums=1), in_axes=(None, 0), out_axes=(0))

u_X = vmap(grad(u_function, argnums=1), in_axes=(None, 0), out_axes=(0))(params, X)
```

However, when I try to do this again to obtain the second derivative :

```
u_X_func = vmap(grad(u_function, argnums=1), in_axes=(None, 0), out_axes=(0))
u_XX_func = vmap(grad(u_X_func, argnums=1), in_axes=(None, 0), out_axes=(0))(params, X)
```

I get the folllowing error:

```
[/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flax/linen/linear.py](https://localhost:8080/#) in __call__(self, inputs)
    186     kernel = self.param('kernel',
    187                         self.kernel_init,
--> 188                         (jnp.shape(inputs)[-1], self.features),
    189                         self.param_dtype)
    190     if self.use_bias:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I tried using the hvp definition from the autodiff cookbook, but with *params* being an input to the function just wasnt sure how to proceed.

Any help on this would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `u_function` maps a length-3 vector to a scalar. The first derivative of this is a length-3 vector, but the second derivative of this is a 3x3 hessian matrix, which you cannot compute via `jax.grad`, which is only designed for scalar-output functions. Fortunately JAX provides the `jax.hessian` transform to compute these general second derivatives:

```py
u_XX = vmap(hessian(u_function, argnums=1), in_axes=(None, 0), out_axes=(0))(params, X)
print(u_XX.shape)
# (32, 3, 3)
```